# c:when not null/empty check using jstl empty

Tags: spring-mvc, null, jstl

I am getting problem of checking null using jstl. when i am displaying value using el. It is showing null But when i am checking in condition.It is always giving me true.

Here is my jsp code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<c:set var="test" value="${fn:trim(sample.testType)}" />
 <td>
 <form:select path="xyz">        
    <c:if test="${not empty test}">
    <form:option value="${sample.testType}" label="${sample.testType}" />
    </c:if>
 </form:select>
 </td>
```

But when i am trying to display value  ${sample.testType} it is displaying null.

Thanks 
Ravi Kant

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong here.

EL does not display null for references which are pointing to null. If you are seeing the words "null" printed, its because your `sample.testType` value is the string "null".

Otherwise your code should work, its a little weirdly programmed but it should work for null references.

Comment: so how can i change "null" to null or check "null" in jsp

Comment: I can't tell you how to make sure you are not setting testType as "null", that's your code. or check it as string in the jstl as in testType eq 'null'